# Z-index and Opacity on several nested divs

Tags: javascript, html, css, z-index

I am trying to have a simple design with three nested divs (Div 3 inside Div 2 inside Div 1), each overlaid on top of each other (Div 3 overlaid on Div 2 overlaid on Div 1). The middle div (Div 2) has a certain level of opacity, such that the outermost div (Div 1) is visible to some extent. However, the div which is the top-most div (i.e. Div 3) should be completely visible and the opacity of Div 2 should not affect Div 3.

Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/maverickdebx/cxLcm161/).  Child 2's opacity is getting affected by Child 1's opacity, which I don't want to happen. I want Child 2's opacity to be 1.0. How can I do this? Please test on Chrome and Firefox.

Following is the html part:

```
    <html>
     <head>
     </head>
     <body>
       <div class="parent box">
         Parent
         <div class="child box">
           Child
           <div class="child2 box">
             Another Child
           </div>
        </div>
       </div>
     </body>
    </html>
```

Following is the css (note that I need position: absolute for both the children):

```
    .box{
         width:200px;
         height:200px;
     }

    .parent {
         background-color:green;  
    }

    .child {
         background-color:blue;
         left:40px;
         top:40px;
         z-index:10;
         position:absolute;
         opacity:0.35;
     }

     .child2 {
         background-color:green;
         left:40px;
         top:40px;
         z-index:100;
         position:absolute;
      }
```

Comment: opacity doesn't "stack". once you set the opacity on some element, all children of that element will always have the same opacity as well.

Comment: Why do the div's have to be nested?

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible, opacity affects all childs. Use

```
rgba(r,g,b,a)
```

for the elements instead.

Example:

```
.parent {
  background-color: rgba(28,179,239, 0.35)
}

.child {
  left:40px;
  top:40px;
  z-index:10;
  position:absolute;
  background-color: rgba(28,179,239, 0.5)
}

.child2 {
  background-color:green;
  left:40px;
  top:40px;
  z-index:100;
  position:absolute;
}
```

<kbd>[See here](https://jsfiddle.net/cxLcm161/10/)</kbd>

Comment: The problem is that, I can't set a static background color for Child 1 because Child 1's background color in my original code (which I didn't write here) is dynamic. It changes based on some actions by the users. So, I want it to have an opacity of 0.35, no matter what color is being used, but not want Child 2's opacity to be affected.

Comment: Then transform it from hex to rgb - problem solved! :-) @maverickdebx. BTW. there's no other option for you

Comment: Ok, thanks @Michael. Based on your suggestion, I think transforming from hex to rgb and rendering that will help. I'll try that. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Break the tree of the nested divs: You don't need to change your HTML, but set the background color and opacity that is now in the child div to a pseudo element of it.

This way you break the dependency in the opacity channel

```css
    .box {
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px;
    }
    .parent {
      background-color: green;
    }
    .child {
      left: 40px;
      top: 40px;
      z-index: 10;
      position: absolute;
    }
    .child:after {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      top: 0px;
      right: 0px;
      bottom: 0px;
      left: 0px;
      background-color: blue;
      opacity: 0.35;
    }
    .child2 {
      background-color: green;
      left: 40px;
      top: 40px;
      z-index: 100;
      position: absolute;
    }
```

```html
<div class="parent box">
  Parent
  <div class="child box">
    Child
    <div class="child2 box">
      Another Child
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```